# How to login as human labeler on GCP Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I set up a Labeling Task in Vertex-AI, and assigned a team.
The manager of that team received an email to manage the https://datacompute.google.com/ console.
None of the human labelers received such an email.
What do they have to do to start labeling? Is there a console for them?

Any advice would be amazing!
Thanks!

Comment: Vertex AI for data labeling seems to be super buggy and confusing. I've created an issue on the GCP public issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/274337636

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new labeling task in the Vertex AI Web UI, the "Customize labelers" step says, "Group managers are responsible for adding and managing labelers and tasks through the DataCompute Console."

I haven't tried it myself, but my guess is that the Group manager will be able to manage the labelers and tasks through the DataCompute Console, and then the labelers will be able to sign into the Datacompute Console to perform the labeling tasks assigned to them by the Group manager.